# How To Kill Threads Using Flags

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, kivy

I'm new to threading and I came across this code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/) and I can't understand the structure and flow of it and how can I modify it to fit my needs.

```
# Python program showing 
# how to kill threads 
# using set/reset stop 
# flag 

import threading 
import time 

def run(): 
    while True: 
        print('thread running') 
        global stop_threads 
        if stop_threads: 
            break

stop_threads = False
t1 = threading.Thread(target = run) 
t1.start() 
time.sleep(1) 
stop_threads = True
t1.join() 
print('thread killed')
```

Can anyone explain this to me? I'm trying to kill threads in a Kivy GUI I'm building but I have trouble understanding the flow of this code and exactly at what point does the flags change and the thread gets killed. My aimed application of this code can be found in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786565/kivy-starting-and-stopping-threads-when-button-is-clicked). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, the flow is something like this:
When you do `t1.start()` it will call the target function which is `run()` and it will continue executing in while loop. After 1 second completes `time.sleep(1)`, we are explicitly setting `stop_threads = True`, which means that the while loop breaks, and thread can be joined(completed).